# Ignore tap gesture in AKPageFlipper application

Tags: ios

AKPageFlipper responds to both swipe and tap gestures. My requirement is that I need to place some buttons in the view that is shown using AKPageFlipper. Hence, I want it to ignore tap gesture. Can anyone give me ideas on how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the source, so you could fork it and add the feature, but looking at it:

https://github.com/mtabini/AFKPageFlipper/blob/master/Classes/AFKPageFlipper.m

You could subclass and override `tapped`, also, you could remove the tap gesture recognizer -- if pageFlipper is your AKPageFlipper object:

```
   [pageFlipper removeGestureRecognizer:pageFlipper.tapRecognizer];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, pageFlipper is my AKPageFlipper object, and I called removeGestureRecognizer the way you have shown here, but it still responds to taps. I put this line in ViewDidLoad() method. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: doesn't seem possible.  Is pageFlipper non-nil at the time of the call?  Is it an outlet -- if so, is it connected in IB?  you could also do `pageFlipper.tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 10;` or `[ pageFlipper canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:yourtaprecog];` or a bunch of other ways (read the UITapGestureRecognizer docs) -- also, you have the page flipper source -- you could remove the tap gesture recognizer completely from it.